# Different screw and their material purpose for computers

Tags: computer-architecture

At our computer store, I had a luck to get to screw sorting (uh, how I like that) and got to question: is there any guide/rules, where should each of them be used. There are different color/material, like: silver/light-blue, quicksilver, orange/gold, black (coated?), yellow/greenish, and maybe some more. What are material properties of each? Does black coating gives anything more than look? Does black coating with gray end mean something?

There are different head caps, like: round with flat washer, round with jagged washer, round with philips, truss with philips, flanged-hex/Phillips-head combined, pan with Slot/Philips combined, flat with philips, and many more (currently counted about 70 types).

There are tapered shanks or a non-tapered shanks, and at least three different shank sizes: fine, normal and large (for FAN/Cooler mountings etc).

Most of them I have usd learning from experience, seeing "what others do". BUT, is there any good-style where each of one should be used? Maybe, there are some with better electrical conductance, good for motherboard grouding/chassis points, others are good for vibrations with breaking head base, maybe others have high durability, others are good for plastic parts, others are non rusting. I don't know, please, guide me.

Some pictures from another store:

- [Cross round head with washer bolt, Steel, nickel plated, M3*.5, 5mm](http://img.alibaba.com/wsphoto/v0/440944682/M3-5-100PCS-mainboard-screw-computor-screw-BOLT-cross-with-washer-round-head-machine-screw.jpg)
- [#6, 1/4" long, 6.3mm, Philips hex head, 6/32 large thread screws. nickel plating.](http://img.alibaba.com/img/pb/631/239/364/364239631_918.jpg)

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question will be closed.

Comment: Maybe a fit for superuser?

Comment: @LeonHeller Don't you ever screw your PCB to chassis with screws? I would like to know, if there is any difference between screws and their material, considering, they are used for high-precision electrical equipment screwing.

Comment: Have you read the Faq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really only 2 factors governing screw use:

1. Thread pitch/diameter.
2. Shank length.

There is primarily two threads used in a computer.  There are the "small" ones (M3?) which are used for CDROMs, Floppy drives and (depending on case) sometimes motherboard mounting.

Then there are the larger ones.  These are usually for hard drives, motherboard mounting, and case assembly.

Any others are usually specific to a manufacturer (e.g., special ones to attach a fan to a heat-sink, etc.)

Most of the time the screws are interchangeable within the groupings.  The only thing to watch is the length of the shank.  When screwing into say a hard drive, if the shank is too long there is a good chance it may impact with the circuit on the hard drive and cause damage.

The shape of the head is largely irrelevant, but can sometimes give a good indication of the rest of the screw style at quick glance.  The case assembly / motherboard mounting are usually hexagonal in shape.  These tend to have a longer shank.  The round, flat headed ones in the same pitch are generally shorter, and are used mainly for hard drives.

Often 'special' head shapes/configurations are used to make it easier for machines to assemble the components.

As for materials and colours, well, that's largely down to style and cost.

And washers?  I have never come across anything but insulating paper washers in computers.  Maybe some serrated or split-ring ones in the construction of the case - these are used as non-slip washers that generally go in areas where there may be vibration.  The paper washers are there more for mechanical protection that electrical.  The sponginess prevents over-tightening of the screws and damaging of sensitive circuits.

Comment: Washer head http://img.alibaba.com/wsphoto/v0/440944682/M3-5-100PCS-mainboard-screw-computor-screw-BOLT-cross-with-washer-round-head-machine-screw.jpg You see, its nickel plated. What difference is nickel/other?

Comment: It's cheaper than stainless steel, and the wide flange makes it well suited for screwing through the slots of drive housings into CDROMs and floppy drives where there is often only a 50% grip surface available.

Comment: So, nickel plating main property is price. What are other platings for? Have seen light blue (steel? zinc? no coataing?), and yellow (brass?).

Comment: Yellow like the big one http://www.screwmakerchina.com/1-1-spring-washer-sems-screw-20.html and what about black ones.

Comment: Cost, style and perception.  Brass-looking screws are perceived as being higher quality than plain silver ones.